# slick.js extra space at the end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I am using slick.js to display multiple logo from a phpmyadmin database just like [this one](http://data:image/png;base64,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) but there's a space at the end of the logos:
I am not sure why this happens and I don't know what I'm missing in my code. The infinite function is not properly running probably? .Can someone help me? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logo-slider').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 100,
      slidesToShow: 6,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      arrows: false,
      variableWidth: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 6,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            infinite: true,
            dots: false
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="logo-wrapper" class="logo-slider" style="background: rgba(143, 143, 143, .8);">
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/facebook-3-logo-png-transparent.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/instagram-icon-white-on-black-circle.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/twitter-3-logo-png-transparent.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Discord-Logo-700x394.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/instagram-icon-white-on-black-circle.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/facebook-3-logo-png-transparent.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/instagram-icon-white-on-black-circle.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/twitter-3-logo-png-transparent.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Discord-Logo-700x394.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/instagram-icon-white-on-black-circle.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/facebook-3-logo-png-transparent.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/instagram-icon-white-on-black-circle.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/twitter-3-logo-png-transparent.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Discord-Logo-700x394.png">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-container" style="height: 50px;">
          <img class="logo-image" style="object-fit:fill; height:100%;  filter: grayscale(100%); margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/instagram-icon-white-on-black-circle.png">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe it's adding some kind of extra style, please add a reproducible example instead of posting an image

Comment: Hello, Thank you, I've edited the post. I am not sure if the problem is in the css but I think it's in the javascript because I also have another slider that slides from one image to another unlike this one that slides to multiple divs, I'm just not sure where the problem exactly is.

Comment: I'm not seeing an extra space in the example?

Comment: I noticed that it only have an extra space if I am using the entire laptop screen as the display but if I switch on mobile or make the browser width smaller there's no extra space